# Android: NullPointerException when add data binding

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

**Now, I can fix it. I remove some tag from layout xml.**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` <<<< Remove this tag from all layout xml.

---

I add data binding to my android project. I got **NullPointerException** from Gradle.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:MaterialDesign:generateDebugSources, :MaterialDesign:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:MaterialDesign:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MaterialDesign:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MaterialDesign:checkDebugManifest
:MaterialDesign:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MaterialDesign:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MaterialDesign:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MaterialDesign:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MaterialDesign:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:MaterialDesign:prepareDebugDependencies
:MaterialDesign:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE 
.
.
.
:app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug
line 1:0 extraneous input '?' expecting {COMMENT, SEA_WS, '<', PI}
line 1:0 mismatched input '?' expecting {COMMENT, SEA_WS, '<', PI}
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 12.924 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

If I remove this (below), I can build the project normally.

```
databinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Comment: Could you post the XML where you are using dataBiding ? It seems an XML error

Comment: Look in your XML for empty spaces or weird characters/symbols at `line 1:0`

Comment: Thank you danypata and Morales Batovski. Now I can fix it. 
I remove this code from all layout xml. It's work. :D
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`